# Primefaces datatable filter kill set paginator

Tags: primefaces

I want to keep filter and current page after updating PrimeFaces dataTable.
To do it I am trying to filter a datatable after a update with a commandlink. Then I will put the same page before filtering.

I use Primeface 6.0

```
<p:commandlink action="#{bean.updateBD}" update=":form" oncomplete="PF('table').filter(); PF('table').getPaginator().setPage(#{myBean.indexPag})>
```

I use this for setting page.

```
<p:ajax event="page" listener="#{bean.update}"/>

public void update(PageEvent event) {
        int var = event.getPage();
        setIndexPag(var);
}
```

But after de action the paginator position return for pag 0 and ignore de value of indexPag.

If I made another commandbutton and put onclick `PF('table').getPaginator().setPage(#{myBean.indexPag})`, if I click after filtering and paging datatable it works. But I need to do it with previous commandlink.

Comment: Why not use the `first` attribute and calculate it based on the rows per page and page number? Saves you an ajax call.

Comment: Can you put me an example? I am not sure I understand.

Comment: `<p:dataTable  first="#{mybean.firstRow}"` and in the getter return your rows multiplied by `indexPag`

Comment: I haved tried but not working

Comment: 'Not working' is a statement by an enduser... Not a helpful description from a developer point of view. Might even be your scope is wrong and things got reset or whatver.. [mcve] please (And version info!)

Comment: @Kukeltje suggestion would do the trick, check also if that page still exists, after filtering

Comment: And try in, a [mcve], a newer PF version